# How to sort FB Shares by likes

Tags: facebook, sorting, share

is possible to sort the fb shares, of a status update for example, by the links of each share?

I will send a example:

Lets say that I update something in my timeline (or a Fan Page timeline), may 100 people share this, I wanna know, the share that have more likes...

Is possible get the page shares details, like this:
http://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=449680915063964

But FBQuery dont analyse this..

Awaiting

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way through Facebook Open Graph api to get such info